# Knockoutjs SyntaxError missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use the `attr` binding to set an attribute (`data-rating`) but I'm getting the error message:

> Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: SyntaxError: missing : after property id;
>   Bindings value: attr: { data-rating: UserMovies[0].Rating }

Does the attr binding not accept hyphenated attributes?

```
<ul class="content thumbnails" data-bind="foreach: movies, loader: $root.isLoading">
    <li class="movie">
        <div class="image">
            <img data-bind="image: { src: Poster.Detailed, alt: Title }" />
            <div class="actions">
                <!-- ko if: UserMovies.length > 0 -->
                <span class="raty" data-bind="attr: { data-rating: UserMovies[0].Rating }"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How did you get the Bindings value? It doesnt even show that one for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should wrap attribute name with a `quote`, and if UserMovies is observableArray you should unwrap it using `()`:

```
<span class="raty" data-bind="attr: { 'data-rating': UserMovies()[0].Rating }"></span>
```

Comment: Especially as you have `data-rating` which will be interpreted as a subtract without quotes around them.

Comment: Link to knockout documentation about this issue: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

Comment: Didn't intended to vote down but click wrong .... So I edit it and remove the down vote. Sorry.